# How to send AJAX form without using HTML <form> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to send data to my PHP using AJAX but without using the HTML `<form>` tag because in my case if I have the form I have a loop of sending the form and AJAX PHP came into looping so I think I would not use form but how can I apply these if AJAX had a method of `POST`?

```
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function(){  
    $.ajax({
        url: "insert.php",
        method: "post",
        data:{data},    
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
            alert('Successfully')
        }
    })
})
```

and my **HTML** is:

```
<div class = "myDiv1">
      <input type = "text">
      <input type = "button" id = "myButton">
</div>
```

Is there a possible way to do this? I'm just asking. Thank you :)

Comment: What behavior are you getting right now? What errors are in the console?

Comment: Give your button the ID of myButton ?

Comment: your code is correct. Just put inside your variable data the values of the inputs, assigning to them an id as "input1" and "input2" and retrieving the value with `$('#input1').val()`

Comment: do i still need the method POST?

Comment: i know how it works by getting by input values and the other functionalities but.. what about the `method: POST`

Comment: What method do you *want* to use if not POST? The default is GET, so if you omit it, it'll be a GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign values to data in ajax like

```
var formData = {
value1 = $(element1).val();
value2 = $(element2).val();
// and so on
}
```

Pass the formData to ajax

Answer (score 1):

#### Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function(){  
    $.ajax({
        url: "insert.php",
        method: "post",
        data:{
            text: $('.text-value').val()
        },    
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
            alert('Successfully')
        }
    })
})
```

#### HTML

```
<div class = "myDiv1">
    <input type = "text" class="text-value">
    <input type = "button" id = "myButton">
</div>
```